# How to use the direct link to modal window

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to use the following code:

```
function popModal() {
   // code to pop up modal dialog
}

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash.substring(1) == 'modal1') {
   popModal();
}
```

How would I use it with the following Modal example:

```
<a href="#" data-target=".bs-nps-modal" data-toggle="modal">
```

Comment: Are you asking how to open a modal with an anchor link, or with an external URL?

Comment: [link](http://example.com) or anchor link.

Comment: example.com/modal?id=modal1 - I was hoping to see something like this that would open the page directly with the popup already open when you get to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kge5rqv3/4/

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
if (hash == 'modal1') {
     popModal();
}

function popModal()
{
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
}
```

**NEW JS:** http://jsfiddle.net/kge5rqv3/7/

```
var id= getUrlParameter('id');

if (id == 'modal1') {
     popModal();
}

function popModal()
{
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
}


function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{

    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);    

    //simulate url http://example.com?id=modal1
    //remove when implementing this code
    var sPageURL='id=modal1';

    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what would be the external URL with this example?

Comment: http://example.com/modal?id=modal1 - I was hoping to see something like this that would open the page directly with the popup open.

Comment: external URL: example.com/#modal1

Comment: get url parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: I must be doing something wrong here. Here is my code:
<a href="#" data-target=".bs-nps-modal" data-toggle="modal">
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade bs-nps-modal" id="modal1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ModalNPS"> is the ID not justified properly in this case?

Comment: <a href="#" data-target=".bs-nps-modal" data-toggle="modal"> - So what happens with the hash - I have an img that triggers the modal on the page. Do I need to add an ID in <a href> tag line?

Comment: I got everything working except that when I put the example.com/modal?id=modal1 to appear into an external link.

Comment: Not sure what is causing it not to popup. Here is my link to my test page: [link](http://convention.cpma.ca/npstest2)

Comment: http://convention.cpma.ca/npstest2?id=modal1 - should work no?unless I'm missing something here - but the code looks good. But for some odd reason it isn't popping open the modal when linking directly to the external URL.

Comment: REMOVE:  var sPageURL='id=modal1';

Comment: My bad. I removed the var sPageURL='id=modal1'; per your comment but it still isn't appearing when I put the direct URL:convention.cpma.ca/npstest2?id=modal1  - am I missing something else or is the URL incorrect?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){

    var id= getUrlParameter('id');
    
    if (id == 'modal1') {
         popModal();
    }
})`

Comment: Excellent! It works! Thanks for all your time.
Steph

Comment: If I wanted to add say 5 modals and have each of them called modal1, modal2, modal3, modal4 and modal5 what method would I used when calling each one using the code you provide above '$(document).ready(function(){ var id= getUrlParameter('id'); if (id == 'modal1') { popModal(); } })'?

Comment: I got to work doing this:`if (id == 'modal2') {
     popModal();
}

function popModal()
{
    $('#modal2').modal('show');
}` 

And adding this: `$(document).ready(function()
{ var id= getUrlParameter('id'); 
if (id == 'modal2') { popModal(); } })`

But I don't think it is a good practice to call each one individually like I'm doing - works but is there a better method? 

I plan to have 54 of these modals being called. Not sure if this will cause any problems to duplicate the code each time.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the accepted solution and needed to debug it.

I think this is a simplified implementation.

```
 function popModal()
{
    $('#modaltopop').modal('show');
}

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    return window.location.search.substring(1);
}

var id= getUrlParameter('link_parameter'); 

if (id == 'link_parameter') {
    popModal();
}


<a href='/?link_parameter'>click me</a>
```

as long as your link parameter matches the parameter in "getUrlParameter('link_parameter')"

samplurl.com/?link_parameter